# I want to validate a textbox to check negative value Like -100?

Tags: javascript, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

i create a simple banking app [This is the Link](https://bankmanagment.herokuapp.com/) For study purpose. alll the function are work charming but i weant to check validation if user enter Negative value like -100 so it shows error or alert message. so how can ii implement.

Thanks in advance :)

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@depositemoney) do |f| %>
  <% if @depositemoney.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@depositemoney.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this depositemoney from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @depositemoney.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :balance %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :balance %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :u_id, :value => current_user.id %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Model.rb**

```
class Depositemoney < ActiveRecord::Base
        # validates :balance, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
        # validates :balance, presence: true
          validates :balance, presence: true
                 # validates :balance, :inclusion => {:in => [1,2]}
          validates :balance, format: { with: /\A\d+\z/, message: "Integer only. No sign allowed." }
end
```

I tried 3 Types of validations but it does not worrk for me so any one can help me out :)

Comment: Presumably your `balance` field is a number, so you'll want to verify that with numerical comparisons, not strings. Have you tried `in: 0..1e9` as an example of a good range?

Comment: i tried rang of 1 to 9999 but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

`:greater_than` or `:greater_than_or_equal_to` option is that.

```
class Hoge < ApplicationRecord
  validates :balance, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
end
```

it works like below:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
[1] pry(main)> Hoge.create(balance: 1)
   (0.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (12.2ms)  INSERT INTO `hoges` (`balance`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2017-10-18 06:06:18', '2017-10-18 06:06:18')
   (11.1ms)  COMMIT


   [2] pry(main)> Hoge.create(balance: -1)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Hoge:0x007fa212e1cd80 id: nil, balance: -1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[4] pry(main)> Hoge.create(balance: -1).errors
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20fcc37c0
 @base=#<Hoge:0x007fa20f6c08f0 id: nil, balance: -1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @details={:balance=>[{:error=>:greater_than, :value=>-1, :count=>0}]},
 @messages={:balance=>["must be greater than 0"]}>
```

FYI: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html